# Expanding macro in \index argument

Tags: indexing, expansion

I have a command `\persName{key}` that expands to the Name of a person represented by a key-string.

I would like to create a command `\eindex` that can have this command as argument, expanding it fully to the name of the person and then using this as argument to `\sindex` (from the `splitidx`-pacakge).

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\persName}{m}{%
    % Only an example. Is more complicated than that.
    John Doe (#1)%
}%

\NewDocumentCommand{\eindex}{o m}{%
    \edef\temp@a{#2}
    \IfValueTF{#1}{%
        \sindex[#1]{\temp@a}%
    }{%
        \sindex{\temp@a}%
    }%
}%
```

But this solution does not work as intended. If I use `\eindex[names]{\persName{Marc}}` it enters

```
\indexentry{\persName {Marc}}{1}
```

into the .idx file. While creating the index, this will get expanded to "John Doe (Marc)", but is ordered under "M" in the index, not "J".

I would like to have `\eindex` expand the mandatory argument prior to entering it in the .idx-file like this:

```
\indexentry{John Doe (Marc)}{1}
```

---

More complicated version of `\persName`:

I use LuaLaTeX and defined a Lua-function (in the external package "Persons") to gather the name of the person in question from an addressbook.

```
\define@cmdkey[pers]{pers}[cT@]{instance}[]{}%
\define@cmdkey[pers]{pers}[cT@]{organization}{}%
\NewDocumentCommand{\persName}{O{} m d() o}{%
    \presetkeys[pers]{pers}{instance=nil}{}%
    \setkeys[pers]{pers}{#1}%
    \begingroup
        \if@emphasize%
            \bfseries%
        \fi%
        \if@color%
            \color{\@pers@color}%
        \fi%
        \luaexec{
            local _case
            \csname IfValueTF\endcsname{#3}{%
                _case = tostring( '\luatexluaescapestring{#3}' )
            }{}%
            local _form
            \csname IfValueTF\endcsname{#4}{%
                _form = tostring( '\luatexluaescapestring{#4}' )
            }{}%
            local _key = tostring( '\luatexluaescapestring{#2}' )
            local _instance = tonumber( '\luatexluaescapestring{\cT@instance}' )
            tex.sprint( Persons.name( _key, { form=_form, case=_case, instance=_instance, } ) )
        }%
    \endgroup%
}%
```

Comment: When you do `\edef\temp@a{\persName{Mark}}` no expansion is actually performed, because `\persName` is protected against expansion in `\edef`. I'm afraid you need to show the “more complicated” working of `\persName` if you want more help.

Comment: That wouldn’t happen if you defined `\persName` with `\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand` (or, for that matter, with `\newcommand`) instead of with `\NewDocumentCommand`; but this may have undesired side effects, so I wouldn’t recommend doing so unless you provide further context for your question.

Comment: I edited the question to add the "more complicated" version of `\persName`. Since the command has an optional argument at the end `\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand` seems not to be the way to go.